# LINQ to XML Append Data throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq, linq-to-xml

Here's the problem I have a xml file that I am trying to append data to.  I am using LINQ to XML and the code I am using is as follows:

```
    public void AppendSalesXMLData(Company company)
    {
        string FileName = "TestSales";
        string OrgID = company.OrgID.ToString();
        string SaleID = company.OrgSales[company.OrgSales.Count - 1].SaleID.ToString();

        if (!File.Exists(String.Format(@"C:\Data-Source\trunk\Applications\VintageSiteInspector\XML\{0}.xml", FileName)))
        {
            CreateXMLFile(FileName);
        }
        XDocument thisDoc = XDocument.Load(String.Format(@"C:\Data-Source\trunk\Applications\VintageSiteInspector\XML\{0}.xml", FileName));

        <!------- The following line throws an exception every time. ----->
        thisDoc.Element(FileName).Add(new XElement("Sale")); 


        thisDoc.Save(String.Format(@"C:\Data-Source\trunk\Applications\VintageSiteInspector\XML\{0}.xml", FileName));
    }
```

The XML file that I am opening is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <TestSales></TestSales>
</root>
```

I just don't see why I am getting a null reference exception.

Comment: Which object/which part is invoking the exception?

Comment: @JamieKeeling The line under <!-- the following line throws an exception every time ---> :)

Comment: Assuming your file name is "Test" then does the xml have an element called "Test" in it? If you are trying to add an XElement to the xml then i guess you need to do something like thisDoc.Add(new XElement("Sale"));

Comment: try this with element value -- thisDoc.Element(FileName).Add(new XElement("Sale","SaleValue"));

Comment: @swapneel tried that I actually have data from the Company object that I was passing in to the element but when it started throwing the exception and I paired it down to the above line so that I could test to see if I could just append a node to the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) refers to direct child (which in your case would be `root`, not `TestSale`). Try `Descendants` instead:

```
thisDoc.Descendants(FileName).First().Add(new XElement("Sale"));
```

Alternatively, when you know XML tree you can also simply walk it like this:

```
thisDoc.Element("root").Element(FileName).Add(new XElement("Sale"));
```